# What impression does it give to say "今日は断食です" at a meal with co-workers?

Tags: words

At least sometimes, I would like to not worry about 割り勘. And (at least initially) I would not like to worry about knowing when and who should オゴリ.

When I'm out with co-workers/friends for lunch, or drinks after work, at least sometimes what if I were to say:

> いや、今日は断食です。

And then just drink water, or maybe just one beer.

How does 断食 sound? Does it make a native speaker smile, shrug, and be like "whatever"? Or does it sound really weird and out of place? It has a strong connotation of Buddhism, right? How strong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say 断食, some people would think you don't eat anything for the reason of your    religion.

I recommend you to say "ダイエット中だから".